# Android Studio: name of keymap/shortcut that displays method parameters hint?

Tags: android, android-studio

Using the latest version of Android Studio.

Once you type the function name and open brackets, AS would automatically display hint with variable type and name (which is really handy). But sometimes it would just disappear.

Does anyone know the keymap (shortcut) that would trigger it to pop again? (haven't found one in AS options, may be I missed one). In particular, I'd like to know the name of the corresponding shortcut so that I can find it through the Preferences screen and update the assigned keys if necessary.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

The command name is "Parameter Info".

On Mac, it's assigned to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> by default.

On Windows, it's assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> by default.

Comment: Yay! Thanks! I had different bind (modified Eclipse), so Ctrl+P was assigned to Print (which I never use). 'Parameter info' is exactly what I was looking for. So happy.. :D

Comment: @ShishirGupta Go to Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion. There you will see a "Parameter Info" section. Check the "Autopopup in (ms):" checkbox. The parameter info will now automatically pop up after 1 second. You can adjust this time if you want. Tested using Android Studio 2.1.1.

Comment: Is there any way to see in chop down mode, instead of the wrap content mode

Comment: Is there a way to scroll through the selection using Tab instead of having to use the Arrow Keys?  Currently, Tab always selects the current selection.

Comment: I must be going crazy because when I try to use arrow keys to cycle through the options, it just moves my cursor in the editor. Is anyone else experiencing this problem? I've tried tab and arrow keys to cycle through the options, but no joy.

Comment: I've tried next and previous on Parameter Info and similar looking options in Keymap, but still nothing. Did this ever work? The window looks like I can't interact with it!

Comment: btw what is the shortcut to add all parameters name? f.e. Person(id = , name = , ...) so i could see what the arguments are and start typing right away

Answer (score 4):

And It's form `View` menu, called `Parameter Info`. There is the shortcut on menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To display a dropdown version of all the available parameters, you can use `Ctrl` + `Space` to show a dropdown list.